# mySQL PDO Prepared Statement Different Results from Non-Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

My experience with PDO is somewhat limited and I've been stuck on this for a while.  The issue is that when I run the code unprepared (because this has proven to be the only way I can debug PDO) I get the results I want.  When I run it as a prepared statement, I get different results.  See below:

***Non-prepared*** code:

```
$interval = array("hourly" => "1 HOUR", "daily" => "1 DAY", "weekly" => "7 DAY", "monthly" => "30 DAY", "yearly" => "1 YEAR");
$intervalString = "INTERVAL " . $interval[$p_sLimitType];

$SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `counted` FROM tbl_transaction" .
       " WHERE type='" . $p_sPostType . "'" . 
       " AND catID=" . $p_nCatID .
       " AND serviceID=" . $p_nServiceID .
       " AND serviceIdentity=" . $p_nServiceUserID .
       " AND timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), $intervalString . ") AND NOW()";

$theQuery = $DB->Query($SQL);
echo "\r\n\r\nQuery:";
print_r($theQuery);

echo "\r\nResult:";
$result = $theQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

***Non-prepared*** results:

```
Query:PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(*) as `counted` FROM tbl_transaction WHERE type='pudding' AND catID=13 AND serviceID=1 AND serviceIdentity=3324848959 AND timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
)

Result:Array
(
    [counted] => 15
)
```

And now the ***prepared code***:

```
$interval = array("hourly" => "1 HOUR", "daily" => "1 DAY", "weekly" => "7 DAY", "monthly" => "30 DAY", "yearly" => "1 YEAR");
$intervalString = "INTERVAL " . $interval[$p_sLimitType];

$SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `counted` FROM tbl_transaction" .
       " WHERE type=:postType" . 
       " AND catID=:catID" .
       " AND serviceID=:serviceID" .
       " AND serviceIdentity=:serviceIdentity" .
       " AND timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), :interval) AND NOW()";

// Execute the statement

try { 
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($SQL);
    $stmt->bindParam(':postType', $p_sPostType, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
    $stmt->bindParam(':catID', $p_nCatID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':serviceID', $p_nServiceID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':serviceIdentity', $p_nServiceUserID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':interval', $intervalString, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    mm_die($e->getMessage());
}

echo "\r\n\$SQL = $SQL";
//          echo "\r\n\$p_nLimitValue = $p_nLimitValue\r\n";
echo "\r\nRow Count: " .$stmt->rowCount() . "\r\n";
```

And the ***prepared*** results:

```
$SQL = SELECT COUNT(*) as `counted` FROM tbl_transaction WHERE type=:postType AND siloID=:siloID AND serviceID=:serviceID AND serviceIdentity=:serviceIdentity AND timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), :interval) AND NOW()
Row Count: 0
```

Note "Row Count" being zero in the prepared statement.  I've stared at this for more time than I care to admit.  Can anyone see why one returns results and the other does not?  Thanks!

Comment: well your first body of code (if it's your actual code) contains a syntax error somewhere, and syntax highlighting says so. Where it is, I don't know (yet).

Comment: I don't think you can do this `SELECT COUNT(*) as counted`. Use a column instead.

Comment: Strange. I only subbed out my original variable with "CatID".  Less identifiable, I felt.

Comment: if PDO failed => http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php it will tell you. and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Well, it works with the non-prepared code.  I can't do that with a prepared statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument to `DATE_SUB()` must be an interval, but you're providing a string. The string `"INTERVAL 1 HOUR` is not automatically converted to the corresponding interval. You can only use a placeholder for the numeric part of the `INTERVAL` expression, not for the keywords.

Take the time units out of the associative array, and represent everything as hours.

```
$interval = array("hourly" => 1, "daily" => 24, "weekly" => 7*24, "monthly" => 30*24, "yearly" => 365*24);
```

Then you can do:

```
$SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `counted` FROM tbl_transaction" .
       " WHERE type=:postType" . 
       " AND catID=:catID" .
       " AND serviceID=:serviceID" .
       " AND serviceIdentity=:serviceIdentity" .
       " AND timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :interval HOUR) AND NOW()";
```

and

```
$stmt->bindParam(':interval', $interval[$p_sLimitType], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Sidenote: `:interval HOUR)` - OP's using an array of different options. They're going to have to change it to `:interval DAY)` etc. for different options. I think they're wanting to do this dynamically. Unless there's something I missed in their method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I do that in my values of `$interval`, by multiplying the number of days by 24 hours/day.

Comment: Ah yes. After going over your answer again, I picked up on it. Thanks for the nudge ;-)

Comment: Partial credit to @Your Common Sense.  The code above worked, along with using "fetchColumn()" to detect the no results state.

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder could not represent an arbitrary part of query, but complete string or numeric literal only.

Thus you cannot bind a part of interval.

As long as you have your intervals *whitelisted* in the code as shown above, you may and you have to stick with old approach for interval.

Comment: AH!  @Your Common Sense.  This was one of the things I suspected but couldn't find a definitive answer on.  So, how do I determine a no results condition using the non-prepared way?  I can't use mysqi_num_rows because it's PDO, no?

Comment: First of all, you never need such a function like num rows in PHP. Just fetch your results and see whether anything has been fetched or not. Either way, I don't understand how is such a function related to your problem. As it said above, there is always a row returned by count(*) query

Comment: By the way, your error reporting is wrong. You should enable exceptions for PDO but shouldn't catch them. See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors for the details.

Comment: It's my organic migration to PDO at fault, no doubt.  I was getting an error when nothing was being returned.  In the past, non-PDO time, I would use mysql_num_rows to check for no results.  Thanks for the link.  It looks to be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for a `select count(*)` to return 0 rows. It will always return AT LEAST **one** row, containing the count of the matched/found rows. Getting 0 rows means your query failed outright, and didn't return a result set, period.

Did you enable exceptions in PDO? By default it does "return false" for failure, and won't throw exceptions unless you explicitly enable them. if they're not enabled, then your `try/catch` is useless.

Comment: Exceptions are enabled in the script.  Do I have to enable PDO exceptions differently?